# Magento 2: How to reduce column width in admin grid?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.8

I want to change column width. I don't want any scroller due to a large column width in admin grid.

Here is the code. I am using:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="api_params">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">API Parameters</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">api_params</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
        <argument name="width" xsi:type="string">60</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-id</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: try 60px instead of 60 in width argument value

Comment: Hi @Piyush thanks for suggestion but its not working.